# Airflow having issues importing from files in a the same specified path as the execution file

Tags: python, airflow

In order to structure my code effectively, I use `sys.path += [ PATH_TO_MODULE ]` to import functions into my DAGs.

The structure is like this:

```
- MODULE
 |_run.py
 |_aux_functions.py
 |_config.py
```

It throws errors while importing `config` in `aux_functions`.

`aux_functions` is imported in `run.py`.

DAG Code:

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow                           import DAG

from MODULE_PATHS import PATH_TO_MODULE
import datetime
import sys

sys.path += [ PATH_TO_MODULE ]

from run import run_function

default_args = { "start_date": datetime.datetime( 2018, 8, 20 ) }

with DAG( "run_dag_v1", default_args= default_args, schedule_interval= "0 0 * * *", ) as dag:
    task = PythonOperator( task_id= "run_function", python_callable= run_function, provide_context= True )

task
```

The `run.py` imports `aux_functions` which imports `settings from config` during it's run which isn't working. The error showing up is:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'settings'`.

```
# run.py
import aux_functions
.....
def run_function( **kwargs ):
    .....
```

```
# aux_functions.py
from config import settings
.....
```

```
# config.py
settings = { ..... }
```

When the code is executed just in the shell it works fine with no issues, however when it is run through airflow, it keeps showing this import error.

The testing is done via: `airflow test run_dag_v1 run_function 2018-8-21`

If I move the `settings` from the `config` to the `aux_functions` it works fine but why does this happen and how can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 1):

So the directory structure is something like this:

```
|_MODULE_1
|   |_ run.py
|   |_ aux_functions.py
|   |_ config.py
|   
|_MODULE_2
    |_ code.py
    |_ config.py
```

What had happened was that one DAG was importing `sys.path += [ PATH_MODULE_1 ]` and another DAG was importing `sys.path += [ PATH_MODULE_2 ]`.

During the runtime of Airflow, it would have the path of the wrong config, so either of the DAGs was always failing. Hence the Import Error, because the other config did not have the `settings` object. They were never both operating correctly at the same time.

The solution was just to make sure that in each case, the `import config` was relative: `import .config`. By doing this, Airflow could now identify the correct `config.py` in each case.

I found that the best way to manage this was importing the parent folder path `from MODULE_PATHS import PATH_MODULES_DIRECTORY` and adding `__init__.py` files to the modules as well as using only relative imports when calling other files inside the same module.

So the new DAGs all have the same `sys.path` and all the modules can be imported with their module names.

```
MODULES_DIRECTORY
    |
    |_MODULE_1
    |   |_ __init__.py
    |   |_ run.py
    |   |_ aux_functions.py
    |   |_ config.py
    |   
    |_MODULE_2
        |_ __init__.py
        |_ code.py
        |_ config.py
```

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow                           import DAG

from MODULE_PATHS import PATH_MODULES_DIRECTORY
import datetime
import sys

sys.path += [ PATH_MODULES_DIRECTORY ]

from MODULE_1.run import run_function

default_args = { "start_date": datetime.datetime( 2018, 8, 20 ) }

with DAG( "run_dag_v1", default_args= default_args, schedule_interval= "0 0 * * *", ) as dag:
    task = PythonOperator( task_id= "run_function", python_callable= run_function, provide_context= True )

task
```

```
# run.py
import .aux_functions
.....
def run_function( **kwargs ):
    .....
```

```
# aux_functions.py
from .config import settings
.....
```

```
# config.py
settings = { ..... }
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative solution. Can you explicitly say what is `from MODULE_PATHS import PATH_MODULES_DIRECTORY` in your example? it is unclear to me.